# HttpClient caching mechanism c#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, dotnet-httpclient

I am using HTTP Client in c#. HTTP client has its internal caching mechanism and I wanted to know **how its caching mechanism works**?

I tired reading many posts and blogs. Those only states regarding the "how to cache" and "how not to cache".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: HttpClient itself doesn't have a caching mechanism itself.  It uses caching capabilities from the platform.  On the desktop it uses the WinInet cache.  I've yet to find the component on Windows Phone that provides the caching services.

Comment: You can use the Cache-Control request header with the no-cache directive on the phone to avoid using out dated content.  Although on the desktop, that header is not implemented.  On the desktop you need to use a trick with if-modified-since and the current date and time.